# ¿Como puedo sobreescribir un archivo .txt borrando todo lo anterior en java?

Tags: java

Tengo un documento de texto con esta información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer que al ejecutar el programa no aparezca repetido dos veces si que no se sobrescriba y aparezca como en la primera imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui os dejo mi codigo:

```
package ficheros;
import java.io.*;

public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       FileWriter fichero = null;
        PrintWriter pw =null;
        try{ 
            fichero = new FileWriter("F:\\Ejercicio1\\Ejercicio1.txt",true);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);
            for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
              pw.println("Linea "+i);
            
        }catch (Exception e0){
            e0.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if (null!=fichero){
                    fichero.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código que has mostrado estás creando un FileWriter pasandole el segundo parámetro a true. Este parámetro es "append", lo que significa que si lo pasas a true vas a concatenar la información y no vas a sobreescribir el fichero. Si quieres sobreescribirlo borra el parámetro (o pásalo a false).

Te dejo la documentación de FileWriter
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

```
package ficheros;
import java.io.*;

public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       FileWriter fichero = null;
        PrintWriter pw =null;
        try{ 
            fichero = new FileWriter("F:\\Ejercicio1\\Ejercicio1.txt");
            pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);
            for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
              pw.println("Linea "+i);
            
        }catch (Exception e0){
            e0.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if (null!=fichero){
                    fichero.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
fichero = new FileWriter("F:\\Ejercicio1\\Ejercicio1.txt",true);
```

por

```
fichero = new FileWriter("F:\\Ejercicio1\\Ejercicio1.txt",false);
```

Documentación: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)